# Generar e informar los primeros N múltiplos de un número M entero

Tags: python

Es un ejercicio de algoritmo que estoy haciendo en python y me esta comiendo la cabeza, estoy aprendiendo de forma autodidacta y no tengo profesor, lo que llevo haciendo es:

```
#inputs

M=int(input("Ingrese el numero que desea saber sus multiplos --> "))

N=int(input("Ingrese cuantos multiplos quiere generar --> "))

#variables

i=0

#matematica
   
while (i<N):
       
 if M%0:
       
     print()
   
i=i+1  

print("fin")
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres hacer?

Comment: el ejercicio pide "Generar e informar los primeros N múltiplos de un número M entero" y por generar entiendo que pide 2 inputs, el print() esta vacio porque no se que poner para que de como resultado el numero que da como resto 0 indicando que es multiplo

Comment: Esta expresion M%0 significa "hace M dividido 0 y decime que resto te da". No se puede dividir por 0, por lo que te debería tirar un error. Es por eso que recurres a este foro?

Comment: si, tira "  if M%0:
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero" como hago para que divida por la cantidad N y devuelva los que den como resultado cero, indicando que sea multiplo

Comment: Te seré sincero, no tengo ni idea de como ayudarte sin hacer el ejercicio por ti... Dejame pensar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es simple: tienes que iterar sobre el número de múltiplos pedido. En cada iteración, múltiplica la base por la iteración que llevas (1, 2, 3, ...).

La única complicación es que `range` parte contando de cero por default, y aquí lo necesitamos que parta de 1. Por eso ocupamos el formato `range(comienzo,fin)`.

```
# inputs
M = int(input("Ingrese el numero que desea saber sus multiplos --> "))
N = int(input("Ingrese cuantos multiplos quiere generar --> "))
# matematica
for i in range(1, N + 1):
    print(M * i)

print("fin")
```

produce:

```
Ingrese el numero que desea saber sus multiplos --> 45
Ingrese cuantos multiplos quiere generar --> 3
45
90
135
fin
```

Comment: Yo pensaba en evitar hacer el ejercicio por el. Así aprende a hacerlo por si mismo. Pero si no queda de otra, está bien, demosle la forma de hacerlo y ya...

Comment: entiendo tu " que aprenda solo" pero programar conlleva generar una mentalidad nueva por mi parte, y a veces necesitas un empujon para hacer el AH asi era como se hacia, aprecio tu ayuda Dante

Comment: Gracias, la verdad espero que hayas aprendido algo por que eso es lo más importante c: Tomaré en cuenta lo del empujon!

Comment: Por cierto, si quieres apoyar a Candid Moe por su dedicación lee este link para saber que hacer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @DanteS. La forma de aprender es mirando a otros resolver problemas. Siendo un principiante, entienden mejor por el ejemplo que por la teoria.

Comment: Entiendo los puntos de ambos, gracias Candid Moe y Javier c: